# Deleting a cell from UITableView from another UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have two view controllers, `TypeViewController` and `FavoritesViewController`, `TypeViewController` consists of a type that can be favorited by pressing a `UIBarButtonItem`. Pressing the button saves the type to an array and saves that array to a file. `FavoritesViewController` opens that files and uses its array to populate a UITableView, which I do in it's `ViewDidLoad` method, and then at the end, I add `[self.tableView reloadData]` to be sure the tableView will be populated. However, I noticed when I try to un-favorite a type (by pressing the `UIBarButtonItem` again), it won't remove from the tableView. I have no idea how I should go about this! How can I remove the tableView cell?? Any input would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if I need to give any other details! Thanks =D

---

Here is some code:

From `TypeViewController`:

```
//When The UIBarButtonItem is pressed
-(IBAction)favoriteTheSubject:(id)sender{

//Open the saved array
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *arrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favoritedTypes.dat"];

NSMutableArray *favoritedTypeInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: arrayFileName];
//If the array file does not exist, set the array
if(favoritedTypeInfo == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Didn't exist in SecondaryDetailVC");
    favoritedTypeInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
//Favorite item
if ([self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FavButton.png" ]]) { //FavButton.png is the unselected favorite button
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FavButtonSelected.png"]];//Change the image
     //Add the type
    [favoritedTypeInfo addObject:typeOfObject];
    [favoritedTypeInfo addObject:priceOfType];

    NSLog(@"Added Item");

    [favoritedTypeInfo writeToFile:arrayFileName atomically:YES];
} 
else{ //Unfavorite Item
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FavButton.png"]];
    //Create an array to insert all the values to remove
    NSMutableArray *removeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [favoritedTypeInfo count]; i++) {
        NSString *sameTitle =favoritedTypeInfo[i];

        if ([self.tableTitle isEqualToString:sameTitle]) {
            //Add typeOfObject and priceOfType to removeArray
            [removeArray addObject:favoritedTypeInfo[i]];
            [removeArray addObject:favoritedTypeInfo[i+1]];
            NSLog(@"Removed %@", removeArray[i]);
        }
    }
    //Remove objects
    [favoritedTypeInfo removeObjectsInArray:removeArray];
    [favoritedTypeInfo writeToFile:arrayFileName atomically:YES];
}
}
```

From `FavoriteViewController`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
//Open the array from file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *arrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favoritedTypes.dat"];

NSMutableArray *savedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: arrayFileName];
if(savedArray == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't Open Favorites Array");
}else{

    for (int i = 0; i < [savedArray count]; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            //Array for favorited typesOfObject
            [self.favoritedTypesInfo addObject:savedArray[i]];
        } else if (i%2 == 1){
            //Array for favorited priceOftypes
            [self.favoritedPriceTypes addObject:savedArray[i]];
        }
    }

    //Test to see if there are duplicate objects in arrays
    int countFavorited = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.favoritedTypesInfo count]; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < [self.favoritedTypesInfo count]; k++) {
            NSString *kString = [self.favoritedTypesInfo objectAtIndex:k];
            NSString *iString = [self.favoritedTypesInfo objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([kString isEqualToString:iString] && kString.length == iString.length) {
                NSLog(@"%@ : %@", kString, iString);
                countFavorited += 1;
                if (countFavorited > 1) {
                    [self.favoritedTypesInfo removeObjectAtIndex:k];
                    [self.favoritedPriceTypes removeObjectAtIndex:k];
                    countFavorited = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Did you delete that type in the array?

Comment: yes! and I re-wrote it to the file after I deleted it. I forgot to add, if I close my app and then re-run it on xcode, or if I stop its process completely, it will update the table, but I want it to update the table right away

Comment: show some code so that someone can show you where's the actual problem ?

Comment: sounds like it has something to do with the way you are retrieving your data. I would set some breakpoints and inspect your data to see where it's not getting updated. This is just on the data side, nothing to do with the tableView.

Comment: I added some code, and I put NSLog's in the code before to check, the files do get removed from the saved array, but I don't know why they still show up in the table view, I will check once more, in case I missed something

Comment: Well, I feel extremely slow right now...It was an extremely easy fix! I had initialized my array `self.favoritedTypesInfo` in my `FavoritesViewController` in `ViewDidLoad`, all I had to do was initialize it in `ViewWillLoad` on top of all my other code...Thanks for the suggestions guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying the deleteRowsAtIndexPath, but it would constantly give me an error I didn't understand, but I found the fix, and it was extremely easy. All I had to do was to initialize my `self.favoritedTypesInfo` array in `FavoritesViewController` in `viewWillLoad` instead of in `viewDidLoad`. This way, the array will keep on initializing with no objects,and all the objects that are currently in the array that is saved to the file will be placed in the `self.favoritedTypesInfo` array.

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is that you need to send a message to your tableView to actually remove the row. It looks like you are deleting the data from the array but not telling the tableView, which has already loaded the data, to remove the corresponding row.

Use this method in your tableView Controller.

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```